# Unlocking all worlds in Super Mario Run in multiple iOS devices

Tags: ios, super-mario-run

Is it possible to purchase [Super Mario Run](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/super-mario-run/id1145275343)'s "Worlds 1-6" once, and reuse it across multiple iOS devices that share the same Apple ID (e.g., buy it once and use it in your iPhone and iPad)?

I know it is possible to purchase an app in the App Store once and install it in all devices associated with that account - but as this is an "in-app purchase", I wonder if it is subject to different rules.

Comment: Same rule. (If the developer did follow Apples rules).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Polygon](http://www.polygon.com/2016/12/16/13975408/restore-purchase-super-mario-run-unlock-worlds-levels-again), Super Mario Run's "Worlds 1-6" unlock is a non-consumable purchase, as indicated by @Vemonus. While the app itself doesn't have an option to restore this purchase, you should go through the process of purchasing the unlock again. The application will show the following message:

> You've already purchased this. Would you like to get it again for free?

Answer (score 2):

From [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202023), you will have access across different devices, as this would fall under the following category:

> Bonus game levels

Thus, this in-app purchase would be considered a **non-consumable**, which is treated in the following way:

> You buy these items one time, and you can transfer them to other devices that are associated with your Apple ID. If you lose a non-consumable purchase, you might be able to download it again for free.